# How to run a multi nodes solana cluster in my local server?

Tags: solana-program, validator, solana-test-validator, cluster, bootstrap

I want to run a multi nodes solana cluster in my local server, for example, a bootstrap validator with rpc port 8899 and web socket port 8900, and then an additional validator with rpc port 8901 and web socket port 8902, thus I can connect to the cluster and send transactions to the cluster. I have tried many methods but without success. May anyone can give me some instructions or guidance about this question?